# Use Multi-Vehicle Automatic Transmission Fluid

Tags: transmission, automatic-transmission, fluid, atf

Can we use Multi-Vehicle Automatic Transmission Fluid (ATF) for a transmission that Manufacturer specified to use Toyota-IV?

Comment: See this possible duplicate : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/51218/10976

Comment: If the ATF meets or exceeds ALL the specifications of the T-IV then yes, if it does not the NO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from the Star Tribune, of all places: http://www.startribune.com/brand-clearing-up-confusion-over-transmission-fluid/283401841/

The T-IV automatic transmission fluid meets industry specification JWS3309. Here are several automatic transmission fluids that are listed as suitable for T-IV applications: Valvoline MaxLife Dex/Merc ATF, Mobil 1 Synthetic ATF, Castrol Trans-Max Synthetic ATF, Quaker State Ultimate Synthetic Multi-vehicle ATF, Pennzoil Multi-Vehicle Automatic Transmission Fluid — to name just a few. Mobil ATF 3309 is a JWS3309-spec transmission fluid engineered for this application.